How to install sublime-text in ubuntu 24.04?
I have been trying the following procedure:
Download some key:
curl -fsSL https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/sublimehq-archive-keyring.gpg

Edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list and add the line
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/sublimehq-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/

but then sudo apt update gives this output/errors:
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of apt-news.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of esm-cache.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Hit:1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:3 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                                          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                                             
Get:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease [2,536 B]          
Err:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F57D4F59BD3DF454
E: The repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:2
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:2
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:2

Is there a way to fix this? What am I doing wrong? Why can't I just install it with apt get install? Why do extremely complicated?

did you reference this Ubuntu Handbook article for installing the .deb version?

The installation via the "App Center" did work. I just hope I did not just break ubuntu again by trying to follow these other instructions ...
